# 404 error for files from new project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a solution with several projects. One of the projects is startUp. It references to other projects are registered in the reference. I added a new project Adkplatform.mrp.web (right click to add a new project in visual studio).

I want to display a test page in the browser.

For the test.aspx page I get the error:

`Server error in the application '/'. We could not find this resource. Description: http 404. probably, the resource (or one of its dependencies) is deleted, received a different name or temporarily unavailable. Review the following url and verify that it is entered correctly.`

For the test.html page I get the error:*

```
*Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:3333/test.html
Physical Path      D:\WORK\Projects\Test\Software\.Net\Test\test.html
Logon Method       Cookies*
```

I understand it, the search for files in the startUp project.
The test files have Build Action: Embedded Resource

What did I forget to do? In advance, thank.

Comment: Is that published on IIS?

Comment: If you reference a project that exists only in your local computer, yes, of course you'll get a 404. You should either publish the referenced project to a fixed IP server or reference its compiled library instead.

Comment: yes, local IIS server

Comment: My url Is http://localhost:3333/test.html. I have old projects in solution. I create test.html and test.aspx in old projects. Then display pages  http://localhost:3333/test.html is ok

Comment: The service is probably not running for the server.  Check to see if service is running.  Also from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and check if port 5271 is listening.

Comment: 3333 port - ok! All pages load and display from Startup and "old" projects. For example http://localhost:3333/somethingold.aspx (5271 <--> 3333 port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem is in our local snippet. It is necessary for the display to call a method c#   HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider for each assembly. For a new project (and new assembly), it not was done.